# Parameter queries in Datomic

Tags: clojure, datomic

I am [learning about Datomic queries](http://docs.datomic.com/query.html) and was curious about how to do "parameter queries."

This is what I came up with:

```lisp
(d/q '[:find ?n ?x :where [?n :likes ?x] [(= ?x "pizza")]] 
  [['ethel :likes "sushi"]['fred :likes "pizza"]])

=> #<HashSet [[fred "pizza"]]>
```

Is this it, or is there a more more concise / idiomatic way of accomplishing the above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is in the section "Advanced Queries" of the [Datomic tutorial](http://docs.datomic.com/tutorial.html)

Use the `:in` clause

```lisp
(d/q '[:find ?n ?x :in $ ?x :where [?n :likes ?x]] 
  [['ethel :likes "sushi"]['fred :likes "pizza"]] "sushi")

=> #<HashSet [[ethel "sushi"]]>
```

`:in $ ?x` is the parameter clause and the trailing `"sushi"` is bound to `?x`